# Inside test in Geometry Nodes: Is a point located inside the convex hull?

Tags: geometry-nodes

It is easy to compute the convex hull in geometry nodes. It would be very helpful for me to  find out, whether a random point is located inside the convex hull. My nodes setup is displayed in the image.Can this be easily achieved with geometry-nodes? The only possibility that comes to my mind, would be checking each point against every face.

[image]

The solution works for a lot of points but there are errors. I think, I know why.The point can be closer to a small face on the back of the convex hull, than to a large face on the front side. To be on the save side, this test would have to be done for every face of the convex hull.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For each point, sample the nearest surface position. Get the vector from the point to the sampled position. Compare that vector to the normal of the sampled position. If their dot product is greater than $0$, their angle will be $< 90°$ and the point will be inside the manifold convex hull.

[image: node setup]

For reasons I don't understand this answer apparently doesn't work. So I added [an alternative](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/315905/30849).